# Assigning Wikipedia categories through templates

Tags: wikipedia

I have build a rather elaborate template for our internal wiki. If a new article is created using the template there are quite a few places where the user just supplies a "Y" or "N". Depending on the letter another template is loaded containing some information and adding a Kategorie to the new article. The problem with this is however that the templates themselves end up in the same category.

Sorry I don't have a full MWE at the moment. Below is what a template being pulled by the main template might look like.

```
Die Kombination ... möglich.
[[Kategorie:Ding a]]
[[Kategorie:Ding b]]
<noinclude>
Textbaustein für [[Vorlage:Dinger]]

[[Kategorie:V_Dinger]]
</noinclude>
```

Is there a way to not have this template being categorized itself?

Comment: Try `<includeonly>`: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use the tag `<includeonly>...</includeonly>` to mark up text and code that should only be used when the page is transcluded onto another page.

Use `<noinclude>...</noinclude>` to mark up text and code that should only be used on the template and not when the page is transcluded onto another page.

Read more at: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Transclusion#Partial_transclusion